# Angular 4 passing a service to a component from routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 4 application. I have a service that fetches some data from an API and I have a component that should display it. I don't know how to pass the service as an argument to the component. Any help will be profoundly appreciated. This is the best I managed:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

import { Title } from './title';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(

  ) {}

  people: Person[] = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    peopleService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(p => this.people = p)
  }
}
```

I've come across [this article](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/passing_data_into_components.html) which shows how to pass arguments to components, but in my case no component contains HomeComponent, but it's only registered in the routes:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { AboutComponent } from './about';
import { NoContentComponent } from './no-content';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},
  { path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use a service in a component, you must `inject` it. Otherwise Angular doesn't know what it is and where to look for it.

To keep it simple you should add your `service` in your `app.module.ts` file. In the `@NgModule` object, add your `peopleService` to the `providers` key. Something like this.

```
providers: [
  PeopleService
],
```

Make sure that your PeopleService is imported on top of that file of course.

Then in your `HomeComponent` you'll need to inject the service via the `constructor`.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  people: Person[] = [];

  constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.peopleService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(p => this.people = p)
    }
}
```

If you would like to read up on DI, this is a very useful blog post
[Dependency injection in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I did just this and got 

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for PeopleService

the error only went away after I added 

providers: [PeopleService] 

to HomeComponent

Comment: Is your `HomeComponent ` a part of your `app.module.ts`, meaning is it present in the `declarations` array?

If not, that's the problem. Also if you would use this `PeopleService` only in your HomeComponent it's not wrong to just put it as a provider on the component level, but most of the times we make use of a `SharedModule` for that.